# Pass JSON string form one app to another app (Windows 8.1 Apps) C#

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

I'm using custom protocol to open another app from windows runtime app. I am using following code snippet:

`await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("appb://hello"));`

It works fine when there is plain string. But It gives parse error while passing a JSON string.
`Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.`

I'm creating JSON by:

```
 JObject jObj = new JObject();
 jObj.Add("Name", "abcdef");
 jObj.Add("Address", "acvdfs");
 string json = jObj.ToString();
```

It gives JSON as:

> {   "Name": "abcdef",   "Address": "acvdfs" }

Comment: Could you please include what the JSON `string` value is, when using that?

Comment: Also, are you passing the *whole* JSON string to the method? Or are you getting the value you required first, and *then* passing it? If it's the first, it's because of the way JSON works - you will need to get the value by key, first. See here for JSON syntax: http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp - If you can provide the value of your JSON `string`, this will also help :)

Comment: So, you *are* passing the entire `json` string?

Comment: Yes. Like: `await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("appb://" + json));`

Comment: There's your answer, right there. You'll need to get the strings to make up the Uri out of the `json` string *before* passing those to your method

Comment: How do we do that?

Comment: I'll see if I can put together an answer. Hang on

Comment: I have tried encoding this json string but still not working.

Comment: hi Kishor, I tried to convert to base64, but it only works for short json string, may be because of '==' characters at the end when tried to encode large string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is because you're sending the **entire** `json` string to be created as a Uri.

You will need to get the required values out of the string *first*, and *then* pass those to your method.

As an example, let's say your

```
JObject jObj = new JObject();
jObj.Add("Name", "abcdef");
jObj.Add("Address", "acvdfs");
string json = jObj.ToString();
```

code will give you a "`{Name}/{Address}`" output - `appb://abcdef/acvdfs`

Instead of parsing that directly to a `string`, you will need to get the values out first.

Otherwise your

> { "Name": "abcdef", "Address": "acvdfs" }

is what is causing the

> Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.

error.

You could do this in order to retrieve the values from that string:

```
var values = jObj.Properties().Select(x => x.Value.ToString()).ToArray(); // Gives you an array of the values.

var path = string.Join("/", values); // Creates an "a/b" path by joining the array.

await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("appb://" + path)); // Give that path to create the Uri and pass to your method.
```

This code assumes you're only using the keys to create the path the way I have. It will work for any number of keys, as it just joins all the values together with "/" - e.g. `a/b/c/d/e/f/g` etc.

Any questions, just ask :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried exactly the same. It gives `abcdef\acvdfs`in path. But it throws the same error again :(

Comment: Just to clarify, this is assuming that you're using the sample in the same part you've declared `jObj`. If you're retreiving a "proper" Json string from elsewhere, you might want to look into parsing it out a little differently. The JsonConvert class for C# is a lifesaving tool: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_jsonconvert.htm

Comment: Ah, my bad it's giving you a "\" character instead of a "/" for your Uri. Remove the `Path.Combine` and do a `var path = string.Join("/", values);` instead :)